# How can I trim noise from end of a sound file

Tags: linux, sox

I let `Audio-recorder` in Ubuntu record the output of audio (which was google Text to speech). When I stopped the recording, it seems the narration finished and it has recorded many noise of my room!

I tried to remove the noise from the end of the file.
I tried:

```
sox in.wav temp.wav silence 1 0.1 5% reverse
```

However it removed all narration and what I've heard was the noisy sound of room at the end of the file... The parameters are confusing and I tried different combination with no success... please guide me what should I do?

Comment: While an interesting problem, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. (IMHO) Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks, however `sox` is a tag here with questions even more than those in superuser (473 v.s 78)... I think the focus of stackexchange community is on stackoverflow and so, people try it first!